# How to define and perform CRUD on custom entities in drupal

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I've built an application to run on the client side (JavaScript & HTML) which needs to access and updated data on a server.  It has a schema which consists of 5 tables.  I've defined exactly what they should look like in JSON.  I want these to be available as a JSON service served from a Drupal module.  I understand how to use drupal_json_output to provide the results.  I just can't find a simple way to ensure the database table is created for them and then to add and remove items from it.  I'd like to maintain Drupal's independence from the underlying database.  I don't need any search functionality, forms functionality etc.  I just want to use Drupal's Database Abstraction.

At the moment I've tried the following in my install file:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_schema
 */
function rcsarooms_schema(){
    $schema = array();
    $schema['rcsarooms'] = array(
        'description' => 'Stores the structured information about the rooms and staircases.',
        'fields' => array(
            'ID' => array(
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'length' => 10,
                'not null' => TRUE,
                'description' => 'Primary Key: used in the URLs to identify the entity.'
            ),'Name' => array(
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'length' => 200,
                'not null' => TRUE,
                'description' => 'The name used for links in the navigation menues.'
            ),'ParentID' => array(
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'length' => 10,
                'not null' => TRUE,
                'description' => 'The ID of the parent element or "Root" if this is a root element'
            ),'Type' => array(
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'length' => 15,
                'not null' => TRUE,
                'description' => 'page, staircase, house, room or special'
            ),'BathroomSharing' => array(
                'type' => 'int',
                'description' => 'The number of people the bathroom is shared with (0 for unknown)'
            ),'RentBand' => array(
                'type' => 'int',
                'description' => 'The ID of the rent band the room is in.'
            ),'Floor' => array(
                'type' => 'int',

            'description' => 'The floor number (0 is courtyard level).'
        )
    ),
    'primary key' => array('ID')
);

return $schema;         
}
```

And the following in my module file:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu
 */
function rcsarooms_menu(){
    $items['rcsarooms'] = array(
        'page callback' => 'rcsarooms_callback',
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
    );
   return $items;
}
function rcsarooms_callback(){
    drupal_json_output(db_query("SELECT * FROM {rcsarooms}"));
    drupal_exit();
    return;
}
```

This gives the following error when I attempt to navigate to rcsarooms:
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db.rcsarooms' doesn't exist: SELECT * FROM {rcsarooms}; Array ( ) in rcsarooms_callback()

Comment: Could you just clarify, are you essentially asking how to connect to an external database using the Drupal database layer? Or have I missed the point?

Comment: @Clive missed the point - I'm asking how to create a table in Drupal's Database from a module.  I.E.  I've designed conceptually what I want, A table of Rooms, each Room has an ID, Name, Price etc. etc.  I want to store that information in Drupal's Database, then make it accessible to some JavaScript code running on the client.

Comment: Ah that's what I first thought and I've got an answer all ready :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for [`hook_schema()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_schema/7) which Drupal will use to create your custom tables when you install your module. It goes in the `mymodule.install` file.

The [Schema API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--schema.inc/group/schemaapi/7) will tell you everything you need to know about data types etc.

For adding/removing items from the database use the [`db_insert()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--database.inc/function/db_insert/7), [`db_update()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--database.inc/function/db_update/7) and [`db_merge()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--database.inc/function/db_merge/7) functions

Comment: I've included what I've tried so far.  I haven't actually tried inserting any items yet, but I'd expect an empty result, rather than an error?

Comment: It's just saying the table doesn't exist...if the module was already installed before the schema hook was added then it has to be uninstalled and re-installed (not just disabled and then re-enabled) before the schema hook will run. Your best bet would be to install the [Devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel) and visit `/devel/reinstall`, but you can also disable the module then go to the "Uninstall" tab in the module page and uninstall it there. Then go back and enable it and the table should be created

Comment: That works, you've saved my Christmas as I could never have relaxed with this still hanging over my head.
Thanks